# Using django-haystack +Elasticsearch how can I search subsets of a word?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, searchqueryset

If I enter the query "apple" i wish to get the results like "xyzapplexyz","apple","applexyz" and **NOT** like "app" or "appl" . But what I am getting is "applexyz", "app" etc.

I have used EdgeNgram field and I have tried querying using the following :-

1-->> `SearchQuerySet().all().autocomplete(authors=query)`

2-->> `SearchQuerySet().all().filter(authors=query)`

3-->>  `SearchQuerySet().all().filter(content=query)`

4-->>  `SearchQuerySet().all().autocomplete(content=query)`

But none of them gives the required results. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want results like `"xyzapplexyz"`, then you would need to use [ngram analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) instead of `EdgeNGram` or you could use both depending on your requirements. `EdgeNGram` generates tokens only from the beginning.

with `NGram` *apple* will be one of the generated tokens for term *xyzapplexyz* assuming `max_gram >=5` and you will get expected results, also `search_analyzer` needs to be different or you will get weird results.

Also `index size` might get pretty big with `ngram` if you have huge chunk of text